# How to find $1+1/2^2+1/3^2+...$ using Fourier Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

How to find $1+1/2^2+1/3^2+...$ using Fourier Series. I have already worked out that the Fourier cosine series for $f(x) = x$ is:

$x = \frac{4L}{\pi^2} (1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2} \cdots) -\frac{4L}{\pi^2}(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{L}}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}\cos{n \pi x/L}+...)$ where n is odd.

### hint given is to evaluate this expression at $x = 0$. But then I just get $0 = 0$?

Edit, I have already worked out $1+1/3^2+1/5^2+... = \pi^2/8$

Comment: Try adding $1/2^2 + 1/4^2 + 1/6^2 + \ldots = 1/2^2(1 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + \ldots)$ on both sides of your final equation and solve for the sum $S=1+1/2^2+1/3^2+\ldots$.

Comment: Is there anyway to specifically use the hint?

Comment: @dable Probably you would be more likely to get the sort of answer you want if you include more of the original problem as stated. Aleksandar's answer answers the question as written but your edit and comment suggest this isn't what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you proved
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8},$$
the remaining part is easy. Just notice that:
$$ \zeta(2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}+\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2k)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\zeta(2)}{4},$$
hence $\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ gives:
$$ \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x$ over the interval $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$. The Fourier series of this function is

[image]

Using Parseval's identity we obtain,

[image]

Where

[image]

Thus, $|a_n|^2=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

[image]

and,

[image]

Q.E.D